# Django change model fields attributes?

Tags: python, django

If I change the model fields attributes in django should I remigrate them? will it afftect the data that is already stored there? is it safe to make that change in an already running project?

Comment: Make your question a little more specific, what is the change you want to make to your model?

Answer (score 1):

> If I change the model fields attributes in django should I remigrate them?

Yes of course. Until you're willing to throw away your whole existing database,  that is.

> will it afftect the data that is already stored there?

Depends on your exact changes (some field attributes like `blank` or `editable` won't impact the db schema at all, only the Django code).

Now if your schema changes are to affect your data, you can write data migrations too

> is it safe to make that change in an already running project?

Well that's what migrations (schema and data migrations) are for: having a safe, reliable, repetible, testable way to alter your db schema.